# How to push an OpenCV image viewing window into a QT GUI with Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I want to create a GUI with 2 rectangles for viewing videos (one where you see the input video, one where you see the post-processed video).

I want it to be integrated into a QT-made GUI, but I want these video areas to be populated from OpenCV, as an alternative to OpenCV's `cv::nameWindow` method.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know, how to integrate `opencv`'s windows in Qt, but if you get `IplImage` on any stage, it can be easily converted to `QImage` and `QPixMap`, that can be shown on `QLabel`

Comment: As Lol4t0, I do not know how to integrate an OpenCV's video inside some QWidget. But I can answer how to easily do this manually. It is really straightforward.

Comment: @borges Then please answer that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic workflow to do what you desire is:

1. Open the video with OpenCV API (cvCreateFileCapture, for example)
2. Grab IplImage frames from video (cvQueryFrame)
3. Convert them to QImage (see attached code bellow)
4. Show QImage on within a QLabel (QLabel::setPixmap and QPixmap::fromImage)
5. Loop the frame update (using a QTimer, for example, with video framerate)

Code to convert IplImage to QImage (assuming RGB32Bits images):

```
QImage *IplImageToQImage(IplImage *input)
{
    if (!input)
        return 0;

    QImage image(input->width, input->height, QImage::Format_RGB32);

    uchar* pBits = image.bits();
    int nBytesPerLine = image.bytesPerLine();

    for (int n = 0; n < input->height; n++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < input->width; m++)
        {
            CvScalar s = cvGet2D(input, n, m);
            QRgb value = qRgb((uchar)s.val[2], (uchar)s.val[1], (uchar)s.val[0]);

            uchar* scanLine = pBits + n * nBytesPerLine;
            ((uint*)scanLine)[m] = value;
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

The understanding of the code above should be straightforward. Any doubts just let us know.

This "low level" option allows you to manipulate each individual frame before displaying it. If you just want to display a video via Qt, you can use the [Phonon framework](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html#phonon-overview).

Comment: Good answer! But, he asks for C++, you use C API of OpenCV. Also I think cvGet2D is not really efficient if you want to go over every pixel in the image!

Comment: If you use RGB888 for the Qimage you can use the input image directly. Alternatively use cvtColor() to convert to BGRA for better qimage performance

Comment: The problem is that it's significantly slower than using cvShowImage (in its own window)

Answer (score 8):

Here is code that converts a cv::Mat into a QImage. Methods are for 24bit RGB or grayscale floating point, respectively.

```
QImage Mat2QImage(const cv::Mat3b &src) {
        QImage dest(src.cols, src.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y) {
                const cv::Vec3b *srcrow = src[y];
                QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x) {
                        destrow[x] = qRgba(srcrow[x][2], srcrow[x][1], srcrow[x][0], 255);
                }
        }
        return dest;
}


QImage Mat2QImage(const cv::Mat_<double> &src)
{
        double scale = 255.0;
        QImage dest(src.cols, src.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y) {
                const double *srcrow = src[y];
                QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x) {
                        unsigned int color = srcrow[x] * scale;
                        destrow[x] = qRgba(color, color, color, 255);
                }
        }
        return dest;
}
```

Then, you can use the QImage inside a Qt widget. See borges' answer.

Comment: Is there any community that works more on the integration of Qt and OpenCV?? or is it just like that (I mean your code)?! I'm also new and my current interest is this one. Thanks!

Comment: Well, nowadays the highgui module is optionally built with Qt support (imshow will present you with a nice Qt window, with buttons for zoom/pan, save to file, etc.). It originates from a Google Summer of Code project. So OpenCV itself now has functionality that integrates them, in the highgui module. As far as I know, it is not exposed through the API. I don't know if they have plans to do so. It would make a lot of sense, though.