# openCV's namedWindow embed in Qt's QGraphicsScene? program openCV with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

【abstraction】

I am trying to finish a GraphCut segmentation program. Segmentation part is writtern in **openCV** and GUI part is written in **Qt**. Segmentation part works just fine. I have a problem in integrating them, that is, I cannot use scribble function (one function in GraphCut) in GUI.

【openCV's Segmentation part】

The code of scribble on a openCV's namedWindow is as following (it works)

```
namedWindow("Scribble");

Mat myImg = imread(imgFileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

imshow("Scribble", myImg);

setMouseCallback("Scribble", onMouse, 0);
```

in last line, onMouse is the function for scribbling red and blue lines (see pic)

[image: Original Image]

【Qt's GUI part】

I created a ui using QtCreator. The ui is as following pic. Original Image is in QWidget::graphicsView.  To show this original image, I used the following code (it works too).

[image: program]

My code for this:

```
Mat myImg = imread(imgFileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

QImage disImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(myImg.data), myImg.cols, myImg.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);

QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;

scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(disImage));

ui->graphicsView_OriginalImage->setScene(scene);

ui->graphicsView_OriginalImage->show();
```

【My Goal】

My goal is to do scribble in this GUI, (in other word, comnbine openCV's segmentation and Qt's GUI) the goal is something like the following pic

[image]

【What  I  have tried】

Main issue is openCV's `setMouseCallback` function last line in 【openCV's Segmentation part】 takes openCV's **namedWindow** as input and Original Image in 【Qt's GUI part】is given in Qt's **graphicsView**.

So I thought if I could convert
openCV's **namedWindow**
to
Qt's **graphicsView**,
then problem is solved.

I looked up online, trying to use **cvGetWindowHandle** , but it didn't work, (failed code as following)

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;

scene = (QGraphicsScene*)cvGetWindowHandle("Scribble");

scene->addWidget(ui->graphicsView_1, 0);

QImage disImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(myImg.data), myImg.cols, myImg.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);

scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(disImage));

ui->graphicsView_1->setScene(scene);

ui->graphicsView_1->show();
```

Also I read the following post, but it seems not an answer to my question.

[Embedding an OpenCV window into a Qt GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709952/embedding-an-opencv-window-into-a-qt-gui)

Any help is appreaciated. Gracias in Advance.

Comment: I apologize, you add cv:Mat in Scan and not working? maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: My apologize, too long for this post. The core of my problem is how to openCV's setMouseCallback function on Qt's QGraphicsScene.  setMouseCallback( const string &winname, onMouse, 0 ) works on a namedWindow, but I dont know how to make it works in Qt's QGraphicsScene, as in【Question 】 【What I have tried】

Comment: I can give an alternative solution, since I had a project similar to your project.

Comment: I suggest you go purely to QT  , OpenCV  let them work hard on the core , and let the interface be clean QT

Comment: and when you have the interface on QT , you can freely find a place to click, draw, make segmentation ...

Comment: @vahagnAvagyan in that case, I have to rewrite GraphCut algorithm, since openCV library is used in this algorithm

Comment: Yes, you use the algorithms from openCV source, it’s great, but when you showing images,  go to QT

Comment: @vahagnAvagyan Right, that is my goal. However, after showing images, I need scribble function to work on the images, (to take sample points), in order to use GraphCut algorithm.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html